# Looking for Postfix virtual_mailbox_maps lookup for usernames only, not email addresses

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a postfix accepting mails for 2 domains, example.org, example.com and example.net.

I have a single mailbox for the three domains. Emails to USERNAME@example.org, USERNAME@example.com and USERNAME@example.net go to the same mailbox.

I use postfix to manage the domains, accounts and alias.

I use:

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/scripts/sql_virtual_mailboxes.cf
```

with the query:

```
user = username
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE domain='%s' AND active = '1'
```

This works fine but it forces me to add 3 entries in the table virtual_users with the 3 possible emails and the same password because I want users to use any of the three domains to send emails and authenticate themselves.

I would like to modify the Table virtual_users using only the USERNAME and find a query that checks if a USERNAME exist, not the complete email as I have today.

How can I modify the virtual_mailbox_maps query to check for the USERNAME only and not the complete email?

Answer (score 0):

replace %s (email) by %n (username) in

```
user = username
password = password
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE domain='%n' AND active = '1'
```